# Find "a'' basis for $W = [ p(x) ∈ P_5(R) | p(−x) = p(x)]$

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis, invariant-subspace

> $W = [ p(x) ∈ P_5(R) | p(−x) = p(x)]$
>
> If W is a subspace, then find a basis for W.

Hi. So far, I proved that it is a subspace of W but i don't know how to find the basis. What would be my approach?

Comment: To check, $R$ refers to the reals, and $P_5(R)$ refers to 5th degree polynomials over the reals?

Comment: Can you describe, in words, which polynomials $p$ are in $W$?  Can you _guess_ a basis, or the dimension?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**NOTE:** The condition $p(x)=p(-x)$ is for even functions. Thus only polynomials that will be even functions (linear combination of even functions) will survive.

***But here is a rather detailed way of doing this.***

A general fifth degree (or lower) polynomial will have the form
$$p(x)=ax^5+bx^4+cx^3+dx^2+ex+g.$$
For $p(x) \in W$ we need 
$$
p(-x) = -ax^5+bx^4-cx^3+dx^2-ex+g=\color{red}{ax^5+bx^4+cx^3+dx^2+ex+g=p(x)}.
$$
This gives
$$ax^5+cx^3+ex=0 \qquad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}.$$
This can happen only when $a=c=e=0$.
Thus the $p(x) \in W$ has to be of the form
$$p(x)=bx^4+dx^2+g.$$
So a basis for $W$ is $\{1,x^2,x^4\}$.

Comment: You haven't shown that $\{1, x^2, x^4\}$ is linearly independent though.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD the set $\{1,x,x^2,x^3,x^4,x^5\}$ is a standard basis for $\mathbb{P_5(\mathbb{R})}$, so the linear independence is an immediate consequence.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the linear map $T\colon P_5(\mathbb{R})\to P_5(\mathbb{R})$, where for $p\in P_5(\mathbb{R})$, $T(p)=p(x)-p(-x)$. (Linearity is an easy verification.)

Then $W$ is the kernel of $T$, hence a subspace. The matrix of $T$ with respect to the basis $\{1,x,x^2,x^3,x^4,x^5\}$ is
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Gaussian elimination leads to the reduced row echelon form
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
so a basis for the null space of $A$ is given by the vectors
$$
\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}
\quad
\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}
\quad
\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}
$$
and so a basis for $W$ is $\{1,x^2,x^4\}$.